# Power Bi two different filters adding into a same chart

Tags: powerbi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1bBv.png)

Hi, I want to create a chart like the image.

x-axis;Month
y-axis;sales
another y-axis;average of price

and the model data has like more than 100 products.
I want to choose 2 different products and have them in a same chart.

The current chart shows 2 different charts but I want to overwrap them.

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

This, I hope should solve it for you.

1. Use the product in the legend of your graph
2. And also put the product in the filter of your chart (select 2 specific products you want to visualize.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Add - remove `Model` from the X Axis. So move `Model` from the X Axis to the the Legend.